# PosgreSQL - join 2 big tables (million of records)

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, database-design

My problem (simplified) is this:

I have 2 tables:

```
USERS (
    id bigint primary key
)
```

[image]

```
MOVIES (
    id bigint primary key,
    user_id bigint,
    object json
)
```

[image]

I need to create a third table

```
USERS_MOVIES (
    id bigint primary key,
    movies text
)
```

Where `movies` represents a stringified array with json objects.
Currently, I have this sql:

```
INSERT INTO users_movies (id, movies)
SELECT u.id,
    array_to_string(
        array(SELECT m.object
            FROM movies m
            WHERE u.id = m.user_id),
        '$')
FROM users u
```

[image]

The problem is that there are million of rows in each table and this is quite slow. (It's been 1 hour and still going)
Any idea on how to generate this faster?

I tried my script and, for large data sets, it works very slow.

Comment:  Please never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data

Comment: Have you got an index on movies.user_id? Why not just join the two tables rather than using a subquery?

Comment: If I join, I will basically get multiple rows for each user. I do not want that. I want one row per user

Comment: Yes, if you use a join you’d need to re-write your query to achieve the result you want, which in your case you probably need a GROUP BY. However, I think the index issue would be a more immediate fix - assuming there is no index already

Comment: 1) Why? You are replicating `movies` in a worse form. 2) Why mix Postgres arrays with JSON objects? That is another move backwards.

Comment: Also, if this is a performance issue then please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query

Comment: This is slow by design, why don't you use a normalized data model for your relational database?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be beneficial to process the data in smaller batches instead of a single large query. You can achieve this by adding a LIMIT clause to your query and running it in a loop until all rows are processed:

```
DECLARE batch_size INT := 1000;
DECLARE offset INT := 0;
DECLARE total_rows INT;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total_rows FROM users;

WHILE offset < total_rows LOOP
    INSERT INTO users_movies (id, movies)
    SELECT u.id,
        array_to_string(
            ARRAY(
                SELECT m.object
                FROM movies m
                WHERE m.user_id = u.id
                LIMIT batch_size OFFSET offset
            ),
            '$'
        )
    FROM users u;
    
    SET offset = offset + batch_size;
END LOOP;
```